# Can't create a new "system administrator" user

Tags: profile, user, userlicense, system-admin, new

A few days ago I created a new "system administrator" user in this way:

service setup - users - new

user license: salesforce

profile: system administrator

But now I can't. I don't have the option "salesforce" for the "user license" field that is the only license that allows the "system administrator" profile.
Now "user license" has only these options:

```
[...]

partner app subscription

salesforce platform

work.com only

[...]
```

Why is "salesforce" option missing?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you are out of licenses. In Setup, go to Company Information - does it show some licenses available?

Comment: @DanielHoechst You're right. I'm already using the two "salesforce" licenses that I own so I don't have other "salesforce" licenses available. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can only select licenses types that are available. You can check to see if you have any available in Setup under Company Information.

Answer (score 0):

I solved.

I can't visualize the "salesforce" license in the drop-down menu because I have finished the "salesforce" licenses.

One can visualize the licenses that they own in Setup - Company Information.